# Route each locale in angular universal app

Tags: angular, angular-universal, angular-i18n

I followed the Angular documentation to built a separate distributable copy of my angular universal app for each locale.

Steps:

- [created a translation file for each language](https://angular.io/guide/i18n-common-translation-files#create-a-translation-file-for-each-language) and
- [define the locales in the build configuration](https://angular.io/guide/i18n-common-merge#angularjson-for-en-us-and-fr-example) in the angular.json.
- set "localize" and "aot" [option to true in the build section](https://angular.io/guide/i18n-common-merge#generate-application-variants-for-each-locale) of `angular.json` workspace build configuration file.
- `npm run build:ssr`

  ```
  dist/my-app/browser/
   |-- fr
   |-- en
  ```
- modified the server.ts:

  ```
   export function app(lang: string): express.Express {
      const server = express();
      const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/my-app/browser' + lang);
      //rest as default
    }
    function run(): void {
      const port = process.env['PORT'] || 4000;
      const appFr = app('/fr');
      const appEn = app('/en');
      const server = express();
      server.use('/fr', appFr);
      server.use('/en', appEn);
      server.use('', appEn);
      server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
      });
    }
  ```

Now I can open  `http://localhost:4200/en` for english- and  `http://localhost:4200/fr` for french version in the browser.

How to navigate between both url (languages) within my app.component.ts?

Are there other options than:

```
 if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
    window.location.href = url;
  }
```